# jquery get is not getting the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to use jquery get method

this is jtest.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

fdsffdsf

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the page that should get the data from jtest.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>   
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.load("jtest.html", function(data){
  alert("Data: " + data);
});
});
</script>


<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Nothing happens when I run it please help

Comment: Have deployed the code in some server?

Comment: Look if you have errors in console. Remember also that for security policy, the browsers make XHR calls only via http so, if you're running the page as local file (you should see file:// in address bar) then it can't work (unless you override the policy).

Comment: I think you have solved the problem

Comment: is there anyway to override the policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Jquery` code to get data from another page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery.get('jtest.html', null, function(tsv) {
            alert(tsv);
   });
});
</script>

</head>  
<body> 
   <h1>My First Heading</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `<script>` inside `<html>` and `<head>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.load("jtest.html", function(data){
  alert("Data: " + data);
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Also make sure that `jtest.html` is located at the same directory as your current HTML file

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing  `</script>` tag when loading the jquery library!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this work perfectly:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).load("jtest.html", function(data){
  alert("Data: " + data);
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It says data is undefined?

Comment: Data:undefined they are in the same directory I have also given the direct path to the file